# SFMC iOS SDK setup failed because encryption key could not be created or fetched with configuration

Tags: marketing-cloud, ios, mobilepush-ios

I'm starting integration with the iOS SDK. I'm doing a very very basic config. My config has everything disabled, and I only populate the `ApplicationId` and `AccessToken`

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application 
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

  // configure the Marketing Cloud SDK
  NSError *error = nil;
  BOOL success = [[MarketingCloudSDK sharedInstance] sfmc_configure:&error];
  if (success == YES) {
      [[MarketingCloudSDK sharedInstance] sfmc_setDebugLoggingEnabled:YES];
  }
}
```

However I get the following output even with just this:

```
[foundation] SecItemDelete Exception. Error = -34018
 MarketingCloudSDKFoundation+DataUtils.m line: 262
[foundation] setup failed because encryption key could not be created or fetched with configuration {
    accesstoken = ...;
    appid = "...";
    etanalytics = 0;
    inbox = 0;
    location = 0;
    pianalytics = 0;
}.
error Error Domain=MarketingCloudSDKErrorDomain Code=9 "SecItemDelete Exception. Error = -34018" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=SecItemDelete Exception. Error = -34018}
MarketingCloudSDKFoundation.m line: 229
```

Anyone know what might cause this? Why this might be? I've tried it also with the MID and server url populated, still the same output...

Comment: This could possibly be related to incorrect app signing and keychain sharing. See https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/4743 March 21, 2016 answer. Or using a device running pre-iOS9.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is to do with signing as mentioned by Jeff Sylvia's comment. This is because I was running it in the simulator, when you run it in a real iPhone you do not get this error.